# Texts/codes to test for XSS attacks in my software/website

Tags: security, xss, sanitization

Firstly, I do not have any malicious intent out of this question. I would like to know what text to copy paste and test in my text areas and text boxes to see if they are stripped correctly.

Currently I use something as limited as:

```
<script>
alert('xss');
</script>
<a href="www.test.com" onclick="javascript:alert('xss');">test</a>
<img src="http://localhost/logo.gif" onclick="alert('xss');">
```

Can someone provide or suggest a comprehensive list of tests to check if my site is XSS-proof.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse all the `<code>` tags from http://ha.ckers.org/xssAttacks.xml.

Comment: Interesting set of XSS attacks, seems to be a good resource for developing anti-XSS code.

Comment: You can use the human readable format at http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html. The XML sheet is for CAL9000 and similar tools.

Comment: Here's all the examples in one block of text should anyone need it for testing:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64c1c30cef82123cc9fd